# How to create executable file for a Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I wrote a project in Qtcreator using c++.

How can I create the setup file for the project I have written.

I want to make it workable on different computers.

Comment: So you want to create an *installation program*? Or just build the project? Please give us more details.

Comment: I want to create an installation program @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_Installers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are special softwares, I use Inno Setup.